# How to position a div fixed inside another div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, fixed

I have a set of bootstrap nav-tabs and inside these tabs are nice long information sections. Problem is that our team does not want to have all this information on such a long tab so we have made the tabs container element have an overflow: scroll property. This works great but now we are stuck with an impossibly long inline scroll section and it would take a good 30-40 mouse scrolls to get to the bottom. This will lose us site traffic.

I know that the definition of being a fixed position is being fixed relative to the browser window but I am in need of a way to use bootstrap scrollspy nav-list menu inside of the parent div and not have it able to transverse outside of that div. So we need it the same way that the class="fixed-to-top" attribute works so that is a functionable nav menu but no matter what we try it seems that the fixed positioning always reverts back to being relative to the broswer.

Is it possible to do what we are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not a complete implementation, but I hope it gives you an idea of how it could be done. I.e. change the position property if the fixed div goes outside of its parent/container.

```
var $nlm = $('#navListMenu');
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    if($nlm.offset().top < $nlm.parent().offset().top)
        $nlm.css({ position:'absolute', top:0 });
    else 
        $nlm.css({ position:'fixed'});
}
```

Comment: That Answered it :) Thanks a bunch!